# How can I connect my REST API on remote server to my react application on my local machine?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I have built a simple REST API, which I have uploaded onto a remote AWS EC2 server. I am having some trouble connecting a react application on my local machine to this api.

Originally,  I had the API running on my local machine, the same one as my react application, so all I had to do was use localhost when specifying the endpoint in my Axios call.

Now, I have the API running on a server, and I am trying to connect it to the same react application on my local machine. I would really appreciate some guidance on how exactly I can do this. I have tried many variations of using the ip address of the server, and specifying the port on which the api is running, but it doesn't work. Usually it just times out when it tries to search for the connection.

I have tried many variations of using the ip address of the server, and specifying the port on which the api is running, but it doesn't work. Usually it just times out when it tries to search for the connection. I have double checked that the server is running, the api is running on the sever, the port is correct, etc, no matter what I do it does not work, which is making me think I am going about it the wrong way, and there is a proper way to do this that I am not aware of.

Please let me know your thoughts on this issue and how this task is normally done, thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried API Gateway?

Comment: at what port on EC2 is the API running ?
Is that port open ? Check in the firewall inbound rules